# Support refresh on user edit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weblogic

I am wondering do I need to support the feature to refresh user form (share the link for it) while editing a user?

The scenario:
1. **Admin** clicks on **edit user**;
2. Filled **User form** loads on URL `my-domain.com/user/edit/3`;
3. **Admin** refresh the page;
4. The form loads again with fields filled;

Do I need to support this feature (Admin refresh the page and user data is still there)? Is this an unnecessarily extra?

Example scenario if I do not support this feature:
1. **Admin** clicks on **edit user**;
2. Filled **User form** loads on URL `my-domain.com/user/edit`;
3. **Admin** refreshes the page;
4. **Admin** being redirected back to users list;

I am using **React** and the question more specific would look like this:
Do the **form component** need to receive the user in **props** OR the **user form** have to load the user from the server itself by URL parameter (userId)?

Comment: does your question pertain to authentication? if yes, you'll need a way to re-authenticate or keep a session cookie in the front end if/when the user reloads the page.  simply keeping user info in state will not suffice.  is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: You should probably be asking your users or requirement owners if that's a requirement, not us stackoverflow strangers.

Comment: @Nick I am asking what is the best practice.

Comment: I mean, I _guess_ I"d  personally be loading the user details when you're in that form view, but again this is not the correct forum for opinion-based questions (this is one)

Comment: @Farnoosh I am not askin about authentication and session cookie. My question is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's not neccesary.

Do I need to support this feature (Admin refresh the page and user data is still there)? Is this an unnecessarily extra?

Generally when I refresh the page its because I dont want to erase every field.. or the form doesnt have 'reset' button.

Comment: This is **edit user form**, so I will not want to erase the fields